# Concatenate Message In RAISERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What's the proper syntax here?

```
If (@timestamp < (Select PromoStartTimestamp From @promo))
    RAISERROR('Code not valid until ' + (Select PromoStartTimestamp From @promo)
              ,16
              ,1);
```

I've tried:

```
If (@timestamp < (Select PromoStartTimestamp From @promo))
    RAISERROR(N'Code not valid until @starttimestamp'
              ,16
              ,1
              ,(Select PromoStartTimestamp From @promo));
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `%s` as a string substitution parameter in [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx):

```
DECLARE @PromoStartTimestamp DATETIME
DECLARE @PromoStartTimestampString VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @PromoStartTimestamp = PromoStartTimestamp From @promo
SELECT @PromoStartTimestampString = CAST(@PromoStartTimestamp AS VARCHAR)

If (@timestamp < @PromoStartTimestamp)
    RAISERROR(N'Code not valid until %s'
              ,16
              ,1
              ,@PromoStartTimestampString);
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to `Cast(@promostarttimestamp as varchar)` saying `Incorrect syntax near 'Cast'. Expecting Select or (` or when I don't `Cast` I get `Cannot specify datetime data type (parameter 4) as a substitution parameter.`

Comment: +1 for `%s` but you cannot use expressions (CAST) in the RAISERROR parameters. It has to be isntead `RAISERROR(N'Code not valid until %s',16 ,1 ,@PromoStartTimestampCastedToString));`

Comment: You can also add multiple variables eg RAISERROR('Order %s does not have any %s.',16,1, @SalesOrderNo,@CurrentItemNr);