# Incorrect syntax near '@starttimestamp'. Expecting SELECT or (

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Declare @starttimestamp datetime = getdate();
RAISERROR(N'Code not valid until %s', 16, 1, CAST(@starttimestamp AS VARCHAR));
```

Produces an error saying `Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'.` and `Incorrect syntax near '@starttimestamp'. Expecting SELECT or (`

Comment: [Please see my edited answer to your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032914/concatenate-message-in-raiserror/10032939#10032939).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform a function within the raiserror command.  Convert your date to a string first, like this:

```
Declare @starttimestamp datetime = getdate(),
        @TextDate  char(19)
select @TextDate = convert(char(19),@starttimestamp,120)

RAISERROR(N'Code not valid until %s', 16, 1, @TextDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @starttimestamp varchar(20) = cast(getdate() as varchar(20)); 
RAISERROR(N'Code not valid until %s', 16, 1, @starttimestamp );
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Just cleaning up after your posts :-) Just happen to stumble across two answers of yours - since I was interested in the questions you've answered. I'm not stalking :-)